# Which Ubuntu version has more support here and on the forums? 12.04 or 13.10?

Tags: release-management

I am planning to install Ubuntu, but I want something that is stable and I want to count on the support of the community as well because I need it a lot.

My computer is not a standard (meaning I chose the main pieces and there are very few like it on the market) and so support is usually a probem, which I hope to solve by installing the most common and well-known Ubuntu distro.

Should I go for the LTS or for the latest version? If I go for the LTS, will I be capable of installing and testing new apps and programs released in the future?

Comment: Support is the same for all non-EOL versions. There's just no difference.

Comment: The 2 versions do not have that many changes between them since the LTS will get updates the same as 13.10 ;) If you are a desktop user with no special interests (things like a webserver where you host your own website) I would go for 13.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two contrary arguments for this:

- Use what's most actively used. You can work that out with something like the [Steam Hardware Survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey/) (or wherever you can find that sort of breakdown). In this case it suggests the latest version is most popular but remember the biases. Steam survey statistics are gamers.
- Use what's been around the longest. 12.04 *was* the latest release when it was first released and there has now been over a year of people bumping into problems, asking questions and having things fixed.

  While you *might* find more people are currently using 13.10 (and might be more inclined to help you), you'll probably be more likely to be able to help yourself with an older release because the support already exists.

You're speaking as if a 13.10 user won't answer a question about 12.04 but you have to remember that even if the issue is very specific to 12.04, many 13.10 users used to be 12.04 users. Many (myself included) have installs of both. For the vast majority of problems, version means very little so I'd just go with whatever works best for you. It takes about 20 minutes to download and test Ubuntu so I'd spend a little bit of time working out what the best starting point is.

And remember that paid support is available for all supported versions from Canonical. If you're running into so many problems on a daily basis that it's made you make a software decision, you might need more help than the community can give you.